# Beautifulsoup turning <link> into <link/>

Tags: beautifulsoup, rss

I'm trying to download and parse text from some RSS feeds, such as http://rss.sciencedirect.com/publication/science/03043878. Here's a simple example:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('http://rss.sciencedirect.com/publication/science/03043878'),"html.parser").encode("ascii")        
    print(soup)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the original html (if you look at the website directly), links are preceded by `<link>` and followed by `</link>`. But what beautifulsoup prints out replaces `<link>` with `<link/>` and drops `</link>` completely. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong or is this a bug?

PS Tried changing encoding to utf-8 and it still happens.

Comment: `<link>` and `<link/>` are equivalent

Comment: Try with no encoding at all..

Comment: Vivick, I would have been ok with <link/> if it also didn't remove the tag following the link!

Comment: @Vivick - `<link>` - the tag is open,  `<link/>` - the tag is closed. So not equivalent.

Comment: The `link` (as well as for `img`) are "self-closed" tags meaning that they don't have innerHTML content and close themselves (just like `<br/>`). To quote Mozilla's MSN : "as it is a void element, the start tag must be present and the end tag must not be present".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing RSS. RSS is XML. So pass features="xml" into the BeautifulSoup constructor.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def main():
    doc = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('http://rss.sciencedirect.com/publication/science/03043878'), "xml")
    # If you want to print it as ascii (as per your original post).
    print (doc.prettify('ascii'))
    # To write it to an file as ascii (as per your original post).
    with open("ascii.txt", "wb") as file:
        file.write(doc.prettify('ascii'))
    # To write it to an file as utf-8 (as the original RSS).
    with open("utf-8.txt", "wb") as file:
        file.write(doc.prettify('utf-8'))
    # If you want to print the links.
    for item in doc.findAll('link'):
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Outputs in both files and terminal:

```
... <link>
http://rss.sciencedirect.com/action/redirectFile?&amp;zone=main&amp;currentActivity=feed&amp;usageType=outward&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%3F_ob%3DGatewayURL%26_origin%3DIRSSSEARCH%26_method%3DcitationSearch%26_piikey%3DS0304387817300512%26_version%3D1%26md5%3D16ed8e2672e8048590d3c41993306b0f
</link> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The parser can't evaluate the links correctly. For this issue you should use `xml` as your parser instead of `html.parser`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('http://rss.sciencedirect.com/publication/science/03043878'),"xml")
print(len(soup.find_all("link")))
```

Outputs 52 links.

Comment: `html.parser` also produces 52 links. The problem is that the op encodes the `soup` for some reason, and turns it to string.

Comment: Yes, I'm exporting the results to a text file, and I literally want the exact HTML as it appears on the original website. Is there no way to do that in beautifulsoup without messing up the <link> </link> tags?

Comment: Then you don't need `BeautifulSoup` at all. Just use the raw html response and maybe replace some tags, eg: `response.read().replace('<tag>', '<some other tag>')`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that option! (and what Dan-Dev suggested also works)